# Trying to pass form entry (from a sidebar) into a specific column/cell in Google Sheets via Google App Scripts

Tags: javascript, html, forms, google-apps-script, google-sheets

I've looked through many articles regarding my issue, but I was still unable to troubleshoot my problem. I'm trying to create a form in a sidebar where the entries would be concatenated with other (hidden) strings to "generate" a complete URL, and then post that URL into a column in the active sheet. I was able to get the sidebar and the form showing, but I can't seem to make anything else work after that. When I click on Submit, the sidebar goes blank and nothing happens.

Here's my Code.gs:

```js
function onOpen() {
  SpreadsheetApp.getUi()
      .createMenu('Custom Menu')
      .addItem('Show sidebar', 'showSidebar')
      .addToUi();
}

function showSidebar() {
  var html = HtmlService.createHtmlOutputFromFile('Form')
      .setTitle('Link Generator')
      .setWidth(300);
  SpreadsheetApp.getUi()
      .showSidebar(html);
}

function processForm(form) {
  var result = "https://somelink.com/checkout/term?key="+form.partkey+"&metadata=%7B%22morelink%22%3A"+form.cid+"%7D&p_sheet="+form.psheet;
  SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet().getActiveCell().setValue(result);
  Logger.log(form)
}
```

And here's my Form.html:

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://ssl.gstatic.com/docs/script/css/add-ons1.css">

<script>
function handleFormSubmit(formObject) {
    google.script.run.processForm(
      {
        partkey: formObject.getElementById("partkey").value,
        cid: formObject.getElementById("cid").value,
        psheet: formObject.getElementById("psheet").value
      });
}
</script>

<form id="myForm" onsubmit="handleFormSubmit(this)">
  Part Key: <input type="text" name="partkey" id="partkey" required><br/>
  CID: <input type="text" name="cid" id="cid" required><br/>
  PSheet: <input type="text" name="psheet" id="psheet" required><br/>
  <input type="submit" value="Submit" />
</form>
<div id="output"></div>
<p>
<input type="button" value="Close" onclick="google.script.host.close()" />
```

Please note that I'm a novice at JavaScript and everything coding, really.

Comment: @I'-'I I'm sorry, I don't understand. Where would I place 
    google.script.run.processForm(formObject)? And what does 
    preventDefault() do? Sorry, I'm a noob!

Comment: @I'-'I Got it to work! Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Was able to follow @I'-'I guidance and looked over this [documentation](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/html/communication#forms)

I added this to my html file and it solved my issue:

```js
function preventFormSubmit() {
  var forms = document.querySelectorAll('form');
    for (var i = 0; i < forms.length; i++) {
    forms[i].addEventListener('submit', function(event) {
      event.preventDefault();
      });
    }
}

window.addEventListener('load', preventFormSubmit);

function handleFormSubmit(formObject) {
  google.script.run.processForm(formObject);
}
```